# What is the correct way to implement left shift operations using multipliers?

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I require a left shift operation to be done in VHDL. Input is 24 bit and shift amount is by 16 bits maximum.

Left shift operations by n are synonymous with multiplication with 2^n which is to say that:

> x << n = x*2^n.

Normally implementating a left shift operation in VHDL with variable shift amount shall implement a multiplexer e.g implementing a 16 bit shifter on a 24 bit input shall create a 16-to-1 multiplexer. The shift amount n will then select one of the 16 possible 24 bit outputs. This approach can create massive multiplexers that will later limit Fmax in the design.

I have found that alternative to this is to use a multiplier for the shift operation. Using a hard multiplier in place of a mux created from FPGA logic resources shall lead to better Fmax in the design. In this instance the 24 bit input shall be one operand and a 2^n where n has maximum value of 16 shall be the other operand. Here also, n is input to control the shift amount.

I have one confusion here; when using a multiplier we shall have to generate quantity 2^n from the shift amount n. This will require a look up table. In this case it shall become a 16-to-1 multiplxer where n selects the 16 bit mux output. Since we end up with a big multiplexer in this case as well, doesn't this defeat the purpose of using a multiplier?

Comment: Got any pictures how the generated RTL looks for normal and multiplier versions?

Comment: You end up with a large decoder.  Which takes up a lot less logic resources than one large multiplexer for each bit.

Comment: Actually my design could not meet the 100MHz clock frequency requirement. This caused panic. It can run at 92MHz according to fmax of the timing analyser report. I shall see what to do. Implementing pipelined mux to do this might help, if I can absorb its latency into FSM states as I don't need shifted data every cycle.

Comment: If n is fixed at runtime, you have to do neither operation. Just wire the lower bits into the higher bits of the output number and fill up the lower bits with n 0's. But I guess n is variable here.

Answer (score 1):

If your input shift is 4 bits wide, you need 16 LUTs for the 16 inputs of the multiplier, and generate 00001, 00010, 00100 ...

```
A<=INPUT;
OUTPUT <= A  * B;
B(0)<='1' WHEN SHIFT="0000" ELSE '0';
B(1)<='1' WHEN SHIFT="0001" ELSE '0';
B(2)<='1' WHEN SHIFT="0010" ELSE '0';
*etc...*
```

With "free" multipliers, it can be smaller than a barrel shifter.

Usually barrel shifters are made with cascaded multiplexers. 
Something like that :

```
X0 <= INPUT & '0' WHEN SHIFT(0)='1' ELSE '0' & INPUT;
X1 <= X0 & "00" WHEN SHIFT(1)='1' ELSE "00" & X0;
X2 <= X1 & "0000" WHEN SHIFT(2)='1' ELSE "0000" & X1;
OUTPUT <= X2 & "00000000" WHEN SHIFT(3)='1' ELSE "00000000" & X2;
```

You can also use VHDL standard libraries and let the synthesiser decide which implementation is the best :

```
OUTPUT <= ieee.numeric_std.shift_left(INPUT,to_integer(SHIFT));
```